# probability - straw drawing

Tags: probability

There are five straws and two of them are winners. Three people, draw one straw each - straw A first, then straw B, then straw C.  Find the probability that straw C is a winning straw.

Besides using a tree diagram, what other easier method can I use to solve this?

I have found the answers using tree diagram as $2/5$.

Comment: This task is small enough that you can count all of the possible combinations and their probabilities

Comment: Two people draw one straw each, or three people?

Comment: I think OP means that there are $3$ people, each of whom draws without replacement in order

Comment: "Two people, draw one straw each - A first, then B, then C."  Please explain.

Comment: is three people. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: have you noticed your answer is just the ratio of number of winning straws to the total number of straws? Can you find a simple argument to prove this?

> You basically draw find straws one by one, and want to know the probability of the third straw being a winner. By symmetry, the probability should be the same for the first, second, third, fourth or fifth straw, therefore it's just $\frac 25$.